# How to allow code to continue executing after error [JS]

Tags: javascript, error-handling

So, I am making a website. It checks for a URL query. If there isn't one, all my code stops, but I want code to execute even if there is an error. Here is my current code:

```
if (getUrlArg('foo') == "bar") { //do stuff }
```

But if there is no 'Foo' in the URL bar, it throws an error and stops executing the script. How can I continue running the script even if there is no 'foo' in the URL bar?

edit:

The code for getUrlArg is this:

```
function getUrlArg(argname) {
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
  return urlParams.get(argname);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `getUrlArg`?

Comment: I added it. It's a little wierd, but works @John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "try catch block for this"

```
try {
 //code with error
} catch (err) {
 //code to execute after error is caught
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Modify `getUrlArg` so it doesn't throw in some situations. Perhaps an optional second argument `defaultValue` and it doesn't throw if it receives it and the URL doesn't have the argument (it returns `defaultValue` instead).
2. Use `try`/`catch` around the code in the question, ignoring the error.

I'd go with #1.

Here's a rough sketch (ES5) of taking a default value:

```
function getUrlArg(name, defaultValue) {
    if (/*...the arg isn't there...*/) {
        if (typeof defaultValue !== "undefined") {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        throw new Error(/*...the error it's already throwing...*/);
    }
    return /*...the value that was found in the URL...*/;
}
```

then where you use it:

```
if (getUrlArg("foo", null) === "bar") { /*...do stuff...*/ }
```

Or just take an "optional" flag:

```
function getUrlArg(name, optional) {
    if (/*...the arg isn't there...*/) {
        if (optional) {
            return; // Returns `undefined`
        }
        throw new Error(/*...the error it's already throwing...*/);
    }
    return /*...the value that was found in the URL...*/;
}
```

then where you use it:

```
if (getUrlArg("foo", true) === "bar") { /*...do stuff...*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way I can imagine is a bit different condition:

```
if (foo && getUrlArg(foo) == "bar") {
  // do stuff
} else {
  // go on and do other stuff
}
```

Of course, you can add more complex stuff in the `else` statement. If `foo` is unset, the script should go on with what you put in `else`. Otherwise, you can add `foo !== null` too to your `if`. Promises are great, but their implementation depends on what you want to achieve.